# Nested For Loops Printing out in an Array Style

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to learn nested For Loops and with this one I want it to print out a display of the length and width with *'s. In this case of width =3 and Length = 4, the desired output should look like a 3x4 box made of *'s.

Is my For Loop nested correctly? Do I need two For Loops in the case of the Width value is larger than length?

```
int width, length, i, j;

                width = 3;
                length = 4;

                //Print the output
                System.out.print("Here are the stars: ");
                System.out.print("\n");
                for(i=0; i<width; i++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                    for(j=0; j<length; j++) {
                        System.out.println("*");
                    }
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting? is it what you want or is it different? If different what is the expected output? Please post.

Comment: Well, I was going to answer, but everyone is getting downvoted :) Logically, though, you should go top-to-bottom, then left-to-right, so the first loop uses the length, then the inner one should use the width. Then you need to deal with when to print a new line.

Comment: You mention 3x4 as the pattern of stars you want to print. That usually means 3 rows and 4 columns, but apparently you mean the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt since I see everyone switching width and length? I think length means height.

```
int width = 3;
int length = 4;

System.out.println("Here are the stars: ");

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

#### Output

```
Here are the stars: 
***
***
***
***
```

Comment: yes, length does mean height, and this solution works as well. Thank you very much!. I've learned a lot from everyone's explanations :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot print a star in the first loop. This is wrong:

```
for(i=0; i<width; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
```

Here is a correction:

```
int width, length, i, t;

    width = 3;
    length = 4;

    //Print the output
    System.out.print("Here are the stars: ");
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (t = 0; t < length; t++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: `t` should be `j` in the inner loop

Comment: Yeah it is faster if t and j are in the loop

Comment: I had no clue I could print a new line once out of the first part of the loop, that's what was tripping me up the most. Thank you for teaching me something new :) Helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Basically what is going on here is that it is going through and printing the stars line by line. I switched the width and length, because it should go to each line and print out the stars line by line.

```
int width, length;

    width = 3;
    length = 4;

    //Print the output
    System.out.print("Here are the stars: ");
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah it just came to me that I should have the length first and then the width. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Original code

```
for(i=0; i<width; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
    for(j=0; j<length; j++) {
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
```

#### Produces

```
**
*
*
*
**
*
*
*
**
*
*
*
```

Because you are adding a newline after each '*' in the inner loop.  Move the println to after the inner loop.  All your outer loop needs to do is control the number of times the inner loop is executed and print a newline.
Also, you are printing a '*' before the inner loop which is wrong.

Here is what you need

```
    // Print the output
    System.out.println("Here are the stars:");
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This solution prints `length` stars in a line (inner loop) followed by a newline.  It does this `width` times.

Comment: put in some explanation as to what is wrong with the op code and how you solution solves it.

Comment: @Blip I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the correct logic down, you also need to think about performance.  Outputting to a resource has a cost.  I would split up the arrays and minimize writing to System.out.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {   
    sb.append('*'); 
}

final String s = sb.toString(); 
for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) { 
    System.out.println(s); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You specify a 3x4 pattern of stars that usually means 3 rows and 4 columns. But apparently you want 4 rows and 3 columns. That is, length being the number of rows (3) and width (4) the number of columns

```
for(int row = 0; row < length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

As a side note there is no reason and it is in fact bad style to declare `i`, `j` outside the for loops. In the snippet above I declared `row` and `col` variables inside the respective for loops.

Comment: It really is unnecessary to declare i and j outside. The way Java's memory management works, it is faster to just have it declared inside the for.

Comment: Would either of the 2 downvoters bother to comment ?

Comment: Currently won't compile, you don't declare `i` or `j` as `int`. You make a note to not declare them outside, but you failed do it inside.

Comment: @cricket_007 I provided a modified version of the part of the code that was wrong. The code in the OP and the in all the answers doesn't compile either. E.g. it's not defined in a method that is defined in a class

Answer (score -1):

You need to make two small modifications.  Change the inside loop println to a print and then simply add a println after the inside loop as follows:

```
    int width, length, i, j;

    width = 3;
    length = 4;

    //Print the output
    System.out.print("Here are the stars: ");
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
        for(j=0; j<width; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Also...you either need to change your width=2 and length=3 or start your loops at 1.  The current implementation prints a 4-5 matrix.

Comment: So why is it that this works, I set my width loop to start at 1 (as you said) and I got the display that i was looking for. Could you go through it logically for me? would really appreciate it

Comment: Setting the width to 3 and starting the loop at 0 runs through the loop 4 times (0, 1, 2, 3).  So in order to get a 3x4, there are two options.  Either set width=2 and start the loop at 0 (0, 1, 2) OR set width=3 and start the loop at 1 (1, 2, 3).  Similar logic for length.  Does that make sense?